# XPath Get parent element from two children texts

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
<div class="inner-article">
    <a style="height:150px;" href="this is a link"><img width="150" height="150" src="this is an image" alt="K1 88ahiwyu"></a>
    <h1><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/pegroxdya/dao7kdzej">title</a></h1>
    <p><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/pegroxdya/dao7kdzej">subtitle</a></p>
</div>
```

Hello!

I need to find a XPath to get the "div" with the class="inner-article" by Title and Subtitle of the two "a" children. The website I want to operate on has a lot of these inner-articles and I need to find a specific one, only given a title and a subtitle.

E.G.: The website has an inner article with the title "Company® Leather Work Jacket" and a subtitle with its color "Silver".

Now I need to be able to find the "div" element even if I only have the keywords "Work Jacket" for the title and "Silver" for the subtitle.

This is what I came up with already:

```
    e1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + kw + "')]]")
```

kw is a string which contains the keywords for the title and if I print it out it correctly responds the "a" element and clicking on it works too, but it's not specific enough because there are more objects which also have these keywords in their title, which is why I also need the subtitle that always contains the color(Here referred to as string "clr"):

```
    e2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + clr + "')]]")
```

This also works and clicks on the subtitle correctly but only the color would also return multiple objects on the website.

That's why I need to find the "div" element with keywords for the title and the color for the subtitle.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
e1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + kw + "') and contains(.,'" + clr + "')]]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[h1/a[contains(text(),'" + kw + "')] and p/a[contains(text(),'" + clr + "')]]")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more xpath grammar.[Refer to this link](http://www.xmlplease.com/axis)

In your case you can use the xpath like this.

```
("//*[text()[contains(.,'" + kw + "')]]/parent::div[1]")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I also need to implement the subtitle in the XPath because the title alone would not be specific enough and give me more than one result, as I stated.

Comment: you can use "and" statement between two queries.